# Problema con control de tipo DATETIME-LOCAL de HTML5 me devuelve la hora adelantada

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

tengo este control

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <input type="datetime-local" name="fechahora" step="1" min="{{meta.fechaActual}}" ng-model="evento.fechaInicio">
</div>
```

Pero cuando lo pruebo y selecciono por ejemplo la siguiente hora `01/02/2017 12:23:22` el modelo de AngularJS (Angular 1) me carga lo siguiente

```
{"fechaInicio":"2017-03-02T16:22:23.000Z"}
```

Por lo visto, el value retorna 4 horas adelantadas. Porque sucede?

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna respuesta?

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes:

1. `2017-03-02T16:22:23.000Z` Luego del día, donde empieza la letra "T" `T00:00:00.000Z` representa el ISO-8601 completo para las fechas.
2. Te retorna 4 horas adelantadas por el hecho de la hora de tu computadora en base a tu región en comparación al UTC (hora global). Así trabaja JavaScript.
3. Para solucionar eso tienes varias opciones: utilizar esta librería http://momentjs.com/timezone/ o sencillamente trabajar en las zonas horarias correspondientes. En lo personal y aprendido en SOes, se recomienda trabajar en UTC y transformar las fechas en el front-end.

Mayor información aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

```js
d = new Date();
d.setUTCFullYear(2017);
d.setUTCMonth(1); // Febrero
d.setUTCDate(28); // OJO, es 28!
d.setUTCHours(2); // 2 AM
d.setUTCMinutes(45);
d.setUTCSeconds(26);
// -> 2017-02-28T02:45:26.884Z (Hora actual en UTC)
console.log(d); 
//La hora en que me encuentro es GMT-08 (hora del pacífico)
//Por eso sale 8 horas antes, en otras palabras:
//6PM (hora actual en mi zona horaria) + 8 horas (de diferencia con UTC) = 2AM (en UTC)
console.log(d.toLocaleString());       // -> 02/27/2017, 6:45:26 PM 
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());   // -> 02/27/2017 //Esto es lo que buscas
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString());   // -> 6:45:26 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Se debe a la zona horaria en la fecha entregada, ya al escribir `2017-03-02T16:22:23.000Z` se está especificando con la hora UTC (+0) y cuando es impresa es presentada con la hora local, puedes leer mas en https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601.

Puedes imprimir la hora en distintas zonas horarias con [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Ej.

```js
const d = new Date('2017-03-02T16:22:23.000Z')

console.log(d.toLocaleString('ln', {
  timeZone: 'America/New_York'
}))
console.log(d.toLocaleString('ln', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai'
}))
```